# Передать функцию в props дочернего компонента. Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

В официальной документации немного устаревший подход и плохо разъяснен такой простой шаг, как передача функции в props дочернего компонента.

Родительский компонент

```
<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld';

export default {
  components: {
    HelloWorld 
  },
  methods: {
    sampleFunction(){
      alert("Hello world from parent!")
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <HelloWorld 
       @onClick="sampleFunction" /> // Передаю функцию в дочерний компонент
  </div>
</template>
```

Дочерний компонент.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b>Hello World</b>
    <button @click='onClick'>Call parent func</button> //Вызываю функцию
  </div>
</template>

export default {
  props: {
    onClick: 'sampleFunction' //Определяю функцию
  }
};
```

Вместо корректного выполнения функции я получаю:

```
Property or method "onClick" is not defined
```

Comment: `<HelloWorld  @onClick="sampleFunction" />  // Передаю функцию в дочерний компонент`   Не очень понятно. Похоже что данным кодом вы отслеживаете событие `onClick` по которому вызываете `sampleFunction` , разве нет ? Если вам нужно передать в `props` то это `:onClick="sampleFunction"` . Ну и в `props` вы перечисляете входящие свойства, а не определяете их там.

Comment: свойства передаются как :on-click, у вас в примере @onClick - для события. 
В этом случае необходимо вызвать this.$emit('on-click')

Comment: `<template>
  <div id="app">
    <PasswordBox 
      v-on:click='sampleFunction' />
  </div>
</template>`  

`<button v-on:click="this.$emit('on-click')">Press me</button>` 

Попробовал согласно замечанию, результат 

`Cannot read property '$emit' of null`

Comment: В шаблоне без `this.` - он уже в нужном экземпляре – `v-on:click="$emit('on-click')"`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, если оформите как ответ, отмечу правильным.